# c3js / highcharts multi series nested json chart with many data points

Tags: json, d3.js, highcharts, c3.js

I'm currently trying to figure out whether it would be possible to generate a c3js chart from the following json structure.

```
[
  {
    "name": "LineTest1",
    "data": [
      {"date": 1452049754,"value": 118},
      {"date": 1452049759,"value": 120}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineTest2",
    "data": [
      {"date": 1452049758,"value": 54},
      {"date": 1452049759,"value": 59}
    ]
  }
]
```

I've seen mentions in the documentations of using xs or keys: chart options which appear to be setting the x and y axis to a specific key in a flat data array although I haven't been able to find any docs or examples / google related to multi series nested json, or how to handle that.

With the data above the objective is to render 2 lines on a chart.  Line 1 having the *title* of LineTest1 and the Line2 having the title of LineTest2.  The data points for X axis for Line 1 would then use data.date as a timeseries and data.y as the value.

Is this even possible?  If not is there a better way to do this?  If it is possible could someone explain how this can be accomplished?  I would be loading the data via url, however I have also seen some mentions stating that it is better to use d3 to load the json instead of using c3 to do this like:

```
url: '/rest/chart_data_endpoint.json',
type: 'line',
mimeType: 'json'
```

I have not yet been able to get a single chart working with the current json structures so I don't have a fiddle to start with.  My other dilemma is that there may be several lines and each have 5k data points / line?  So I'm curious whether highcharts is not a better option as they seem to claim that you can do 1mil points with an ajax load although I'm still in the same boat with not knowing js or the libraries themselves well enough to know which to pick or where to start.

Comment: why don't you convert the json into the format expected by c3.

Comment: Are you meaning use multiple ajax requests with flat arrays and multiple charts?  Also as in the example above the *date* points and value points is different per line series.

Comment: No i am saying fetch all your data and then convert it  into the expected json with a for loop. If thats simple or you can change teh server side to give the expected data

Comment: Biggest thing that worries me there is a for loop over 50,000 + data points in js, and also how to set the line names dynamically.  I'm looking into this though thanks for that :)

Comment: You can have a loading screen to block users from firing any events while the process is on.
As a suggestion i would say since you have 50000+ points why not do the processing work and making the d of the line path inside web worker. Read this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp ...its more like a thread which will do your non UI wrk